# Copy a single file from workspace in jenkins to another folder

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, artifact-deployer

I want to copy a single file from a folder in Jenkins workspace to an another folder. Currently  I tried to do the same with Artifacts Deployer plugin . [image]
But It's copying the entire folder structure to destination  folder. As below

[image]

I just want to StyleCopViolations.xml to be in DestFolder. I am using windows machine. Please help.

Comment: StyleCopViolations.xml and DestFolder are on the same Windows machine? if yes use COPY windows batch command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Post-build steps, add: Run Batch command

For the Batch command, add these (replacing when necessary):

`COPY [source e.g. your workspace] /A [destination e.g. another folder] /A`

Sources:

This:

`C:\> help COPY`

```
Copies one or more files to another location.

COPY [/D] [/V] [/N] [/Y | /-Y] [/Z] [/L] [/A | /B ] source [/A | /B]
 [+ source [/A | /B] [+ ...]] [destination [/A | /B]]

  source       Specifies the file or files to be copied.
  /A           Indicates an ASCII text file.
  /B           Indicates a binary file.
  /D           Allow the destination file to be created decrypted
  destination  Specifies the directory and/or filename for the new file(s).
  /V           Verifies that new files are written correctly.
  /N           Uses short filename, if available, when copying a file with a
               non-8dot3 name.
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /-Y          Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.
  /L           If the source is a symbolic link, copy the link to the target
               instead of the actual file the source link points to.

The switch /Y may be preset in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless COPY command is being executed from
within a batch script.

To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).
```